# GCC: Is it possible to disable the "comma at end of enumerator list" warning when using -pedantic?

Tags: gcc, enums

I'm compiling C++ code and I'd like to enable the -pedantic option.
I'm using GCC 4.0, running Xcode on Mac OS X Leopard.
It is for example possible to allow variadic macros and the `long long` type that are normally forbidden when using -pedantic (with -Wno-variadic-macros and -Wno-long-long).
But I could not find anything to disable the "*comma at end of enumerator list*" warning.
Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A comma at the end of an enumerator is valid in C99 but not in C89, so the following will work providing your code is valid C99

```
gcc -std=c99 -pedantic foo.c
```

I'm fairly sure that it's not valid in C++ (according to g++) at all

Edit: tested this with GCC 4.2.1 on HP-UX and it works with no errors / warnings
foo.c

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    enum { A, B, };
    return 0;
}


gcc -std=c99 -pedantic foo.c
```

Comment: Indeed, I get a warning when "-std=c89" is used. No warning when "-std=99" is used. But I get an error if I turn foo.c into foo.cpp. That's my problem...

Comment: if it's a .c file then GCC uses a C compiler.  If it's a .cc or .cpp file GCC uses a C++ compiler.  Your code isn't legal C++, hence the error.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ it is not yet possible to disable it, even though it legal in C++11.
So in the future, when GCC is corrected, -std=c++11 should disable it.

-std=c99 only works in C, not C++ (as in the question).

Comment: It seems to have been fixed now: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51888